# What to do about breaking changes that affect existing answers that rank highly in Google search?

Tags: discussion

The update to the R package `data.table` version 1.9.8 comes with the following warning:

Changes in v1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016)

> POTENTIALLY BREAKING CHANGES
>
> By default all columns are now used by unique(), duplicated() and
>   uniqueN() data.table methods, #1284 and #1841. To restore old
>   behaviour: options(datatable.old.unique.by.key=TRUE). In 1 year this
>   option to restore the old default will be deprecated with warning. In
>   2 years the option will be removed. Please explicitly pass by=key(DT)
>   for clarity. Only code that relies on the default is affected. 266
>   CRAN and Bioconductor packages using data.table were checked before
>   release. 9 needed to change and were notified. Any lines of code
>   without test coverage will have been missed by these checks. Any
>   packages not on CRAN or Bioconductor were not checked.

This affects stackoverflow answers coming up in the first page of google for queries like:

```
how to find duplicate rows with data table
how to get unique rows data.table R
```

Namely, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392332/find-all-duplicated-records-in-data-table-not-all-but-one). I am sure there are many other places where the change invalidates other (accepted) answers. The key issue is that none of the accepted answers work without passing a new argument `by = key(DT)` to override the new default.

In general this is not limited to the `data.table` package. Other very popular packages like `ggplot2` (version 0.9.x -> 2.x.x has syntax differences), and `dplyr` (changes the row order of tibbles after operations between versions) are affected as well.

What actions can I or the general community take to make mass changes to these answers?

Comment: What can be done? The developers can read the "breaking changes" documentation before blindly deploying code they find on the web.